# If closed under countable intersection, then also closed closed under countable union

Tags: measure-theory

I am at looking at Klenke's Probability Theory. And he starts if the class of sets $\mathcal{A}$ is $\setminus$ - closed (i.e. closed under difference), then:

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} A_1 \cap A_n = \bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} A_1 \setminus (A_1 \setminus A_n ) = A_1 \setminus \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}(A_1 \setminus A_n ) \in \mathcal{A}$$

I can follow up until the very last $=$.

If I write out the term before the last one and the last one, I get something that is different, so I do not follow:

$$\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} A_1 \setminus (A_1 \setminus A_n ) = A_1 \setminus (A_1 \setminus A_2) \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap \cdots$$

$$A_1 \setminus \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}(A_1 \setminus A_n ) = A_1 \setminus(A_1 \setminus A_2) \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5 \cup\cdots$$

EDIT: I think I am now getting what he is trying to do but I don't get it. He using the property of $\setminus$ - closed there at the very end. But how come those two things are the same... I must be expanding the cups and the caps incorrectly

Comment: You aren't expanding correctly. The first one is $$(A_1\setminus(A_1\setminus A_2))\cap (A_1\setminus (A_1\setminus A_3))\cap(A_1\setminus(A_1\setminus A_4))\cap\cdots$$ and the second one is $$A_1\setminus \Bigl((A_1\setminus A_2)\cup (A_1\setminus A_3)\cup(A_1\setminus A_4)\cup\cdots\Bigr)$$

Comment: The elements of the next-to-last intersection are everything which is in $A_1$ but is not in any $(A_1\setminus A_n)$; that is, it lies in $A_1$ but does not lie in $\cup(A_1\setminus A_n)$; that's precisely the description of the last expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're missing some parentheses.

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = A_1 \cap \bigcap_{n=2}^\infty A_n = \bigcap_{n=2}^\infty (A_1 \cap A_n) = \bigcap_{n=2}^\infty \Big(A_1 \setminus  (A_1 \setminus A_n)\Big)$$

Now recall De Morgan's laws

$$\bigcap_{i\in I} B_i^c = \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\right)^c$$

So, if we consider the complement with respect to $A_1$, we get

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \bigcap_{n=2}^\infty (A_1 \setminus A_n)^c = \left(\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty (A_1 \setminus A_n)\right)^c = A_1 \setminus \left(\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty (A_1 \setminus A_n)\right)$$

Comment: hmm, I am struggling once again to see how you get from the term before the last to the last one...

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal I defined the complement to be taken with respect to $A_1$, meaning for $S \subseteq A_1$ we denote $S^c = A_1 \setminus S$. The sets $A_1 \setminus A_n$ are subsets of $A_1$ so we can take complements and apply De Morgan.